# How to debug PHP using VSCode IDE in Ubuntu

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, debugging, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I need to debug PHP code using VS Code IDE. We can debug PHP using [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/). So I tried a lots to setup Xdebug for debugging but I failed to use Xdebug using VS Code IDE.

```
PHP is 8.1
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
```

Please help me how can I debug.

Comment: "I failed to use Xdebug using Vs code IDE" - what does that mean?

Comment: hey @NicoHaase I shared Step By Step Guide for Use Xdebug in Vs Code. if i make any grammer mistake in question then you can correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:- Install **PHP Debug** Extension in VS Code IDE.

Step 2:- Copy Full output of `Phpinfo()`. run below Command in CLI for get output of phpinfo().

```
php -r "phpinfo();"
```

Step 3:- open [Xdebug wizard Page](https://xdebug.org/wizard) & paste copied full output of `phpinfo()` in the form field. after the submitting form you will get step by step Instructions related to setup Xdebug in your System.

In my system currently I used Php 8.1. see below Snapshot of Xdebug Wizard Instructions.

[image: Xdebug Wizard Instruction for Php 8.1 in Ubuntu]
Follow above Instruction which one you will getting from [Xdebug Wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard)

**Note that,** above Wizard Instructions is as per my server configuration. In your case it may differ than my above snapshot. So, you must need to follow Step 2 & 3.

Step 4:- add below Configuration in your php.ini file.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
    
;Note:- Below Xdebug Path is depends on your OS & your PHP Server. 
;So you need to write path of xdebug.so (in Linux) 
;OR path of xdebug.dll (in windows) 
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20210902/xdebug.so
```

for find Extension Directory for your server (Xampp, Lampp etc. all) then, simply Run `php -r "phpinfo();"` command then find out `extension_dir` as like below snapshot

[image: php extension_dir path using cli]

OR write `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in your php file then run that php file & found out `extension_dir` in your output page of phpinfo.

Step 5:- Restart your Server (Apache).

Step 6:- Install [Browser Extension Initiation](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#browser-extensions). then start debugger in your Vs Code IDE see below snapshot.

[image: start debug mode in VS code to listen for Xdebug]

**Now, All Done.**

---

for referece I share other source urls

> refer [Xdebug Docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/install#configure-php)
> refer for [Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrQWtbxY1Hs)
> refer this for [Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmyxWy8jl7U)

But, before starts debugging your code, if you need to **check Xdebug is working proply or not** then Follow below Steps. otherwise you can ignore below steps.

In Xdebug 3+. there is xdebug_info() method exits which return info of xdebug extension.

write `<?php  xdebug_info(); ?>` in your php file & then run this php file.you will get output as like below snapshot

[image]

& for check Xdebug works properly for CLI run `php -r "xdebug_info();"` in cli.

[image]