# Failed loading Xdebug PHP 7.4.0

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, php-7.4, xdebug-3

I am trying to use Xdebug for coverage and debugging in PhpStorm. I have followed several tutorials, mainly [this one](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#on_demand_mode).

I am getting this error when running `php -v`.

```text
Failed loading C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.1.6-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2019 10:14:18) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

**Environment:**

I downloaded the dll file from [here](https://xdebug.org/download/historical). Specifically

```text
Xdebug 3.1.6
Release date: 2022-11-08
PHP 7.4 VC15 TS (64 bit)
```

Because I have the Thread Safe version.

This is the result of `php -i`

```text
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.4.0

System => Windows NT DESKTOP-094MCJ2 10.0 build 22621 (Windows 10) AMD64
Build Date => Nov 27 2019 10:07:05
Compiler => Visual C++ 2017
Architecture => x64
Configure Command => cscript /nologo configure.js  "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File => C:\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20190902
PHP Extension => 20190902
Zend Extension => 320190902
Zend Extension Build => API320190902,TS,VC15
PHP Extension Build => API20190902,TS,VC15
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => enabled
Thread API => Windows Threads
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, https, ftps, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3
Registered Stream Filters => convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 7.4.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => C:\php\ext => C:\php\ext
file_uploads => On => On
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .;C:\php\pear => .;C:\php\pear
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => no value => no value
serialize_precision => -1 => -1
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
syslog.facility => LOG_USER => LOG_USER
syslog.filter => no-ctrl => no-ctrl
syslog.ident => php => php
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
windows.show_crt_warning => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => 1 => 1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.exception_ignore_args => Off => Off
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

date

date/time support => enabled
timelib version => 2018.03
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2019.3
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => UTC

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.9.10
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512/224 sha512/256 sha512 sha3-224 sha3-256 sha3-384 sha3-512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b crc32c fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => "libiconv"
iconv library version => 1.16

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.internal_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.output_encoding => no value => no value

json

json support => enabled

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.10
libXML Loaded Version => 20910
libXML streams => enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
libmbfl version => 1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 6.9.3

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mbstring.detect_order => auto => auto
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => no value => no value
mbstring.http_output => no value => no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => Japanese => Japanese
mbstring.regex_retry_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
mbstring.regex_stack_limit => 100000 => 100000
mbstring.strict_detection => On => On
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => mysqlnd 7.4.0
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile => Off => Off
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off

mysqlnd

mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 7.4.0
Compression => supported
core SSL => supported
extended SSL => not supported
Command buffer size => 4096
Read buffer size => 32768
Read timeout => 86400
Collecting statistics => Yes
Collecting memory statistics => Yes
Tracing => n/a
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
Openssl default config => C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 10.33 2019-04-16
PCRE Unicode Version => 11.0.0
PCRE JIT Support => enabled
PCRE JIT Target => x86 64bit (little endian + unaligned)

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.jit => 1 => 1
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 7.4.0

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar API version => 1.1.1
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => disabled (install ext/bz2)
OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => WinEditLine

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \> 

Reflection

Reflection => enabled

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user 
Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => no value => no value
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_samesite => no value => no value
session.cookie_secure => 0 => 0
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.sid_length => 26 => 26
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_only_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_strict_mode => 0 => 0
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

SimpleXML

SimpleXML support => enabled
Schema support => enabled

soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Internal Sendmail Support for Windows => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.exception => 0 => 0
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_hosts => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
unserialize_max_depth => 4096 => 4096
url_rewriter.hosts => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => form= => form=
user_agent => no value => no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.10

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

zip

Zip => enabled
Zip version => 1.15.5
Libzip version => 1.4.0

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.11
Linked Version => 1.2.11

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name


PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

At the end of it I added these lines:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.1.6-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port="9003"
```

Which are meant to configure the zend extension.

I am trying to solve this issue, I already tried different Xdebug versions TS, NTS, x64 and x32 (even when I think I need the TS and x64 one).

My expected result is to have the extension working.

**Solution**

As Derick suggested in this question, you need at least PHP 7.4.20 or PHP 8.0.7. I downloaded php-7.4.20-Win32-vc15-x64.zip and it works like a charm!

Comment: If anyone using Linux System & wish to use Xdebug to Debugging in php then see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74558676/14344959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the footnote on https://xdebug.org/docs/compat#versions:

> "On Windows you need at least PHP 7.4.20 or PHP 8.0.7. Earlier Windows builds of PHP do not export the zlib function gzfwrite which Xdebug 3.1 needs for compression of profile and trace files."

You need to upgrade your PHP to at least 7.4.20, and you're running 7.4.0.

Comment: That is incredible. I didn't even notice that footnote. I will try it in a couple of hours, but this solution looks promising.

Comment: You were totally right. It works perfectly with php-7.4.20-Win32-vc15-x64.zip.